# Is it a good idea to buy second hand bike model that has been discontinued?

Tags: road-bike, parts, replacement

I am a new rider looking for a road bike.  I found a deal to buy second hand 2017 Orbea Avant M40 size 51 for $800.  I see that this model is discontinued by Orbea. Will it be a problem to find parts should I need some repairs done in near future?

My last bike was Diamondback Calico - Aluminum frame. I had problem going up on steep hills. At max I have rode a bike for 20 miles in one ride, and my average in the summer would be anywhere from 10 to 25 miles.  This year planning to ride for a 40 miles ride.

Comment: Note that the M40 had a 2017 [MSRP of $1499](https://www.bicycling.com/bikes-gear/a20048440/get-aero-or-go-long-on-the-2017-orbea-orca-and-avant/) (scroll down to the bottom of the article), so the $800 price may or may not be a good deal depending on what shape it's in, and how much life is left on the components.  (i.e. It's not a great deal if you have to replace the entire drivetrain.)

Comment: In addition to the answers, virtually every bike "model" is only made for a few years at most before the manufacturer updates at something about it, such as the frame, and so the same "model" from year to year can vary quite a bit, superficially.

Comment: The drivetrain is apparently Shimano.  Parts should be available.

Comment: The seller is asking more than twice as much as **a quarter of the original price**, which is the most you should expect to get from reselling anything where its equivalent is available new, or there is no intrinsic value in being an antique.

Comment: @Mazura I challenge you to find such a recent bike of this category for such a low price. It is still quite new. If it is in a good shape, you ain't gonna buy it for a quarter. Unless from a desperate seller whose other option is a pawn shop.

Comment: What kind of $ is that price?  AUS, CA, US, or some other dollar?  It makes a difference...

Comment: @VladimirF if this is an entry-level rim brake bike, then Mazura and DavidF may have a point. In my experience, all used bikes tend to be heavily discounted. Rim brake bikes get discounted a lot. Entry-level ones also. I sort of think of used bikes like used electronics.

Comment: My last new-new bike was 1986.  Since then, every bike has been used, some by as much as 30 years.  Its not that big a deal.

Answer (score 21):

Generally it's absolutely fine to buy a relatively new bike, and not worry about component availability.

Bicycles are not like cars that have specific components for each model, or at best some component sharing across a manufacturers models. In general, practically all bicycle components are standardized so that bicycles can be built up (or modified) with components from many manufacturers.

There is an increasing trend for some manufacturers to integrate the seatpost, stem and sometimes handlebars of some models into the frame design for aerodynamics or to facilitate internal cable routing, but the Orbea model you mentioned does not have this.

Comment: Note, though, that there's always the oddball that does use something unique.  I got a GT frame off Nashbar dirt cheap years ago (like $10 marginal cost because it kicked my order up into "free shipping"), but the thing had a weird headset that was a bear to find, and wound up costing more than the frame itself.  So it's always a good idea to check.

Comment: Derailleur hangers are probably the most frame-specific parts, but there are substitutes and "universal" versions available as well

Comment: @AndrewHenle Headsets may be frame specific but generally brands tend to use the same sizing across their production, be it only for logistic reasons.

Comment: I used a couple 20+ year old bikes and never had any problem finding parts for them.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [2017 Catalog](http://content.orbea.com/descargar.php?file=RESUMEN_GAMA_2017_EN_SIN_PRECIO.pdf&folder=PDF%2F%2Forbea%2Fsales%2Fcatalogs%2Flow) on the [Orbea](https://www.orbea.com/) website, the M40 comes with Shimano Tiagra 4700 components, which are serviceable if not fancy.  For an entry bike they'll do fine, and Tiagra 4700 is still the current model per the [Shimano website](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tiagra-4700.html).

Even once Shimano updates the Tiagra line, there will still be lots of older components available and Shimano will usually provide an upgrade path.

In general, if you buy a name-brand bike in the mid-or-better range (which this is) you should be able to find replacement parts for at least a decade, if not 20 years or more.  (Granted, after 10 years it may get harder to *find* them, but they'll be available.)

Answer (score 7):

Maintaining this bike shouldn't be a problem. Although there are all too many standards for bicycles and bike parts, almost all parts are made to *some* standard, and that bike appears to be using up-to-date standards without any especially weird parts. The parts are not made by Orbea anyhow, they're made by other companies, and in any case you'll be able to swap parts that aren't necessarily identical.

As to your cycling goals: Far be it from me to discourage you from getting a new bike (and this does look like a good deal on that bike), but getting up steep hills can be fixed by A) getting fitter, and B) getting lower gears, which you can do without replacing the whole bike.

Answer (score 3):

Adam is correct that it is rarely a problem to find spare parts for discontinued bikes. Most of the items you'd need to replace, like the chain and cassette, are standard items produced by big manufacturers. There are some possible exceptions, but they tend to be minor.

The rear derailer bolts onto an item called the derailer hanger. Almost all derailer hangars are made of aluminum, and are replaceable. If you crash, you could bend the hangar and affect your shifting - and you would generally replace the hangar rather than bend it back (steel hangars can be bent back safely). Orbea is likely to keep stocking derailer hangars for some time, and a dealer would be able to order a replacement. Alternatively, Wheels Manufacturing makes replacement hangars for many bikes. For example, I believe [this one](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hanger-85.html) should fit the bike in question. Wheels' site has a derailer hangar lookup system for you to be sure. There may be other third-party manufacturers, Wheels is just the one I'm aware of. An Orbea dealer is likely to have more specific advice on the best course of action. If you don't live near an Orbea dealer, any bike store might be able to help. I wouldn't be that concerned about this issue, but it is something to be aware of.

I can't tell for certain what bottom bracket standard that bike uses. It may be a pretty common standard known as PF86. *In theory*, if a manufacturer uses a proprietary standard, it's possible that at some point they will cease to support it, or go out of business, or that replacement parts might be harder to find. You can read [one reader's saga](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66312/wilier-oversize-bottom-bracket-bearing-cups-for-shimano-crank) with a Wilier frame that used a proprietary standard that they later discontinued; he tried to change his cranks, and he is still having trouble finding the right equipment. Chances are that's not the case with Orbea. It's possible that bottom bracket shell specifications will change and that PF86 will go extinct at some point in the future. If this happens, it could be hard to source replacement equipment as well. By the time this happens (if it does!), chances are good that you'll be ready for a new bike. I wouldn't worry about this issue.

I can't tell if the bike in question has disc brakes. [One listing](https://www.theproscloset.com/products/2017-orbea-avant-m40-road-bike-55cm-medium-carbon-shimano-tiagra) for an Avant was a disc brake bike, and it described the calipers as a proprietary Orbea brand. Chances are that caliper was made by a big manufacturer (e.g. Tektro) and rebranded. So, chances are decent that you should be able to find a pad that fits when the pads wear out, but it might take some searching. In the worst case, disc brake mounting systems are standardized, so you could replace the calipers wholesale. If the bike in question has rim brakes, this isn't a concern at all. Chances are very good that the bike can take Shimano-style brake pads, and that you can replace them.

(While we usually deprecate product recommendations, many stock pads for lower end rim brakes aren't very good. Many riders will do well to replace them with Kool Stop pads, or find stock Shimano or SRAM pads that fit the holders.)

Comment: According to the [technical manual](http://content.orbea.com/descargar.php?file=TECHNICAL%20MANUAL%20AVANT_OME%202016-2017%28EN%29%2Epdf&folder=PDF%2F%2Forbea%2Fmkg+elements%2Fcatalogs+%26+manuals%2Ftechnical+documents) the BB is "PRESS FIT 86,5 MM. INTERNAL DIAMETRE 41MM" and it only comes with caliper brakes.